# QString's toHtmlEscaped doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, encoding, qt5

I'm writing a `QString` with some non-ascii characters to a html-file like so:

```
QString string = "äöü";
std::ofstream f("myfile.html");
f << "<h1>" << qPrintable(string.toHtmlEscaped()) << "</h1>\n";
```

So I call `toHtmlEscaped()`, but nevertheless I get `Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼`.
More strangely using that particular way to write the string to a file and printing that HTML-file to a PDF leads to correct encoding.

Any pitfall(s) I might have stepped in to?

Comment: `Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼` looks like UTF-8 encoding of `äöü`, misinterpreted as Latin-1. Your code appears to be working as expected.

Comment: Why are you using the u8 macro here? QString is not UTF-8 encoded, so that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks, will remind that in future

Comment: The comment about UTF-8 and QString is just wrong. While QString uses something similar to UTF-16 internally, Qt expects you to write the entire source code in UTF-8. When a QString is constructed it interprets the given char pointer as UTF-8 bytes and how they are stored internally is irrelevant for the user. So both `QString string = u8"äöü";` and `QString string = "äöü";` are equally correct ways to construct QStrings assuming that the source code file is stored as UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you rally want to do is either create a UTF-8 document like this:

```
QString string = "äöü";
std::ofstream f("myfile.html");
f << "<head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"/></head>" << std::endl;
f << "<h1>" << string.toStdString() << "</h1>" << std::endl;
```

or create a Latin-1 document like this

```
QString string = "äöü";
std::ofstream f("myfile.html");
f << "<h1>" << string.toLatin1().data() << "</h1>" << std::endl;
```

In any case you must save your source files UTF-8 encoded as long as you are working with Qt.

---

In both cases you can use toHtmlEscaped to escape `<`, `>`, `&` and `"`:

```
QString string = "äöü<no-tag>";
std::ofstream f("myfile.html");
f << "<head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"/></head>" << std::endl;
f << "<h1>" << string.toHtmlEscaped().toStdString() << "</h1>" << std::endl;
```

and

```
QString string = "äöü<no-tag>";
std::ofstream f("myfile.html");
f << "<h1>" << string.toHtmlEscaped().toLatin1().data() << "</h1>" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Igor mentioned in the comments, the code should work as expected and I cannot see any reason why it shouldn't. Anyways I worked around this by adding `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` into the HTML-file. The code is now just

```
QString string = u8"äöü";
std::ofstream f("myfile.html");
f << "<head><meta charset="utf-8"/></head>\n";
f << "<h1>" << qPrintable(string) << "</h1>\n";
```